# Recursive lambda in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, lambda

I have a structure like this:

```
{"query": {"or": ["ids": [1,2,3], "text": "some text"]}}
```

The structure may vary, but the idea is to exclude the value corresponding to "ids" key.

I wrote a spike, but for some reason it doesn't work as expected, maybe a bug in Python? Or what's more probable it's my mistake:

```
fix = lambda q: {True: {k: '...' if k == 'ids' else fix(v) for k, v in q.items()}, False: {True: [fix(i) for i in q], False: q}[isinstance(q, list)]}[isinstance(q, dict)]
```

Here is a multiline analogy. It works as expected:

```
def fix(q):
   if isinstance(q, dict):
       return {k: ('...' if k == 'ids' else fix(v)) for k, v in q.items()}
   else:
       if isinstance(q, list):
           return [fix(i) for i in q]
       else:
           return q
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You need `{True: lambda: A, False: lambda: B}[condition]()` to selectively evaluate expressions, or else both branches are evaluated anyways and it might cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use more `A if C else B`

```
fix = lambda q: ({ k: '...' if k == 'ids' else fix(v) for k, v in q.items() }
                 if isinstance(q, dict) else
                 ([fix(i) for i in q] if isinstance(q, list) else q))
```